# How to override a function which starts with two underscores in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openerp-7

i work with Openerp 7.0  and i want to override the function __compute defined like the following:

```
class account_account(osv.osv):
    _name = "account.account"
    _description = "Account"

    def __compute(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg=None, context=None,
                  query='', query_params=()):
        """ compute the balance, debit and/or credit for the provided
        account ids
        Arguments:
        `ids`: account ids
        `field_names`: the fields to compute (a list of any of
                       'balance', 'debit' and 'credit')
        `arg`: unused fields.function stuff
        `query`: additional query filter (as a string)
        `query_params`: parameters for the provided query string
                        (__compute will handle their escaping) as a
                        tuple
        """
        mapping = {
            'balance': "COALESCE(SUM(l.debit),0) - COALESCE(SUM(l.credit), 0) as balance",
            'debit': "COALESCE(SUM(l.debit), 0) as debit",
            'credit': "COALESCE(SUM(l.credit), 0) as credit",
            # by convention, foreign_balance is 0 when the account has no secondary currency, because the amounts may be in different currencies
            'foreign_balance': "(SELECT CASE WHEN currency_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COALESCE(SUM(l.amount_currency), 0) END FROM account_account WHERE id IN (l.account_id)) as foreign_balance",
        }
        #get all the necessary accounts
        children_and_consolidated = self._get_children_and_consol(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        #compute for each account the balance/debit/credit from the move lines
        accounts = {}
        res = {}
        null_result = dict((fn, 0.0) for fn in field_names)
        if children_and_consolidated:
            aml_query = self.pool.get('account.move.line')._query_get(cr, uid, context=context)

            wheres = [""]
            if query.strip():
                wheres.append(query.strip())
            if aml_query.strip():
                wheres.append(aml_query.strip())
            filters = " AND ".join(wheres)
            # IN might not work ideally in case there are too many
            # children_and_consolidated, in that case join on a
            # values() e.g.:
            # SELECT l.account_id as id FROM account_move_line l
            # INNER JOIN (VALUES (id1), (id2), (id3), ...) AS tmp (id)
            # ON l.account_id = tmp.id
            # or make _get_children_and_consol return a query and join on that
            request = ("SELECT l.account_id as id, " +\
                       ', '.join(mapping.values()) +
                       " FROM account_move_line l" \
                       " WHERE l.account_id IN %s " \
                            + filters +
                       " GROUP BY l.account_id")
            params = (tuple(children_and_consolidated),) + query_params
            cr.execute(request, params)

            for row in cr.dictfetchall():
                accounts[row['id']] = row

            # consolidate accounts with direct children
            children_and_consolidated.reverse()
            brs = list(self.browse(cr, uid, children_and_consolidated, context=context))
            sums = {}
            currency_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
            while brs:
                current = brs.pop(0)

                for fn in field_names:
                    sums.setdefault(current.id, {})[fn] = accounts.get(current.id, {}).get(fn, 0.0)
                    for child in current.child_id:
                        if not child.active:
                            continue
                        if child.company_id.currency_id.id == current.company_id.currency_id.id:
                            try:
                                sums[current.id][fn] += sums[child.id][fn]
                            except:
                                sums[current.id][fn] += accounts.get(child.id, {}).get(fn, 0.0)
                        else:
                            sums[current.id][fn] += currency_obj.compute(cr, uid, child.company_id.currency_id.id, current.company_id.currency_id.id, sums[child.id][fn], context=context)

                # as we have to relay on values computed before this is calculated separately than previous fields
                if current.currency_id and current.exchange_rate and \
                            ('adjusted_balance' in field_names or 'unrealized_gain_loss' in field_names):
                    # Computing Adjusted Balance and Unrealized Gains and losses
                    # Adjusted Balance = Foreign Balance / Exchange Rate
                    # Unrealized Gains and losses = Adjusted Balance - Balance
                    adj_bal = sums[current.id].get('foreign_balance', 0.0) / current.exchange_rate
                    sums[current.id].update({'adjusted_balance': adj_bal, 'unrealized_gain_loss': adj_bal - sums[current.id].get('balance', 0.0)})
            for id in ids:
                res[id] = sums.get(id, null_result)
        else:
            for id in ids:
                res[id] = null_result
        return res

    account_account()
```

i read that when you want to override a function with double underscores you prefix the method name with one more underscore and the defining classname  as the following:

```
def _account_account__compute(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg=None, context=None,
              query='', query_params=()):
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you read is the double underscore prefixed methods became *private* due to [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). This process rewrites the names inside the class definition to point to the new name. The new name is constructed as you said: `_<class name><class method name>`. Consider the following example:

```
class A():
  def public(self): print('public() called')
  def _internal_use(self): print('_internal_use() called')
  def __private(self): print('__private() called')
  def f(self): self.__private()
```

Now lets take a look at `A.__dict__` which is the structure where methods are stored by name:

```
>>> A.__dict__
mappingproxy({
  'f': <function A.f at 0x1028908c8>,
  '_A__private': <function A.__private at 0x1028906a8>,
  '_internal_use': <function A._internal_use at 0x102890620>,
  '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
  '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
  '__module__': '__main__',
  '__doc__': None,
  'public': <function A.public at 0x102890598>
})
```

Among others, notice you have `_A__private`, `_internal_use` and `public`.

Notice these names does not exist in the module scope, they only exists inside the `__dict__` of the class. When Python is resolving a member access, it looks inside the `__dict__` of the object. If not fount, it looks into the class' `__dict__` and super-classes' `__dict__`.

```
a = A()
a.public
# Python looks into a.__dict__. If not found, it looks into type(a).__dict__
```

This way you can access `public` or `_internal_use` but you can not find `__private` because that name does not even exist. What you can access is `_A__private`:

```
a.public        # works
a.f             # works
a._internal_use # works
a.__private     # AttributeError!
a._A__private   # works again
```

Notice none of this names are defined in the module global scope neither:

```
public         # NameError!
_internal_use  # NameError!
__private      # NameError!
_A__private    # NameError!
```

But you tried to override the function by simply defining a module function with that name. Well, Python member access resolution will never look into the global scope. So you have a couple of options:

1. You can create another inheriting class and redefine that function:

   ```
   class B(A):
     def _A__private(self): print('New __private() called')

     a = A()
     a.f()   # prints __private() called
     b = B()
     b.f()   # prints New __private() called
   ```
2. You can override the method directly with any other function (even a lambda):

   ```
   A._A__private = lambda self: print('This is a lambda')
   a = A()
   a.f()   # prints This is a lambda
   ```

Comment: Thank you alot for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your account_account class that inherits from the odoo class. Then you can override the methods using super():

```
class stock_move(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.account"

    # new columns
    # ...
    def __compute(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg=None, context=None,
              query='', query_params=()):
        # do your stuff
        # call parent method if needed
        return super(stock_move, self).__compute(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg=None, context=None, query='', query_params=())
```

Here an example, overwriting a create method which is very common because you might want to add some extra features when creating an object:

```
class mrp_product_produce(osv.osv_memory):

    _inherit = "mrp.product.produce"  

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        res ={}
        res = super(product_product, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)
        if 'supply_method' in vals and vals['supply_method'] == 'produce':
            sequence_type_obj = self.pool.get('ir.sequence.type')
            id_type = sequence_type_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name': vals['name'], 'code': 'product_produce_' + str(res)})
            sequence_obj = self.pool.get('ir.sequence')
            sequence_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name': vals['name'], 'code': 'product_produce_' + str(res), 'padding': 7, 'number_increment': 1, 'number_next': 1 })
        return res
```